# HOL Theorem Prover: Adding to existing theory

Tags: hol

I am trying to add a theorem to an existing Theory.  The theorem that I am trying to add is:

```
!l1 l2.LENGTH (APP l1 l2) = LENGTH l1 + l2
```

My first step is to prove the theorem; however, when I try to set the goal, I am getting several error messages:

```
set_goal( [],``! (l1:'a list) (l2:'a list).LENGTH (APP l1 l2) = LENGTH l1 + l2``)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should be

```
∀l1 l2. LENGTH (APP l1 l2) = LENGTH l1 + LENGTH l2
```

and

```
set_goal([], ``! (l1:'a list) (l2:'a list).LENGTH (APP l1 l2) = LENGTH l1 + LENGTH l2``)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am able to set the goal; however, I am not able to prove it.  PROVE_TAC doesn't work and ASM_REWRITE_TAC doesn't work either.  Thoughts?

Comment: You need to do an induction. An induction principle for lists is most likely automatically generated when lists are declared. I'm afraid that I've never gotten that far in HOL. Try running `DB.find_in "induct" (DB.find "list");`. Just flicking through the tutorial, it seems that you could better try an `e (Induct_on \`l1\`);`.

Comment: I forgot to add that the first step I attempted was e(Induct_on `l1`) which works fine, but I am still unable to finish off the proof.

Comment: For the base case, you need to rewrite `APP [] l2` into `l2`, then rewrite `LENGTH []` into `0`, then rewrite `0 + LENGTH l2` into `LENGTH l2`.

Comment: For the step case, you need to rewrite `LENGTH (APP (h::l1) l2)` into `LENGTH (h::(APP l1 l2))`, and then into `1 + LENGTH (APP l1 l2)`. And also rewrite `LENGTH (h::l1)` into `1 + LENGTH l1`, and then `(1 + LENGTH l1) + (LENGTH l2)` into `1 + (LENGTH l1 + LENGTH l2)`. Then rewrite `1 + x = 1 + y` into `x = y` before applying the induction hypothesis. I imagine that HOL has tactics to do most of these steps automatically.

Comment: I got it working!  Thanks for your help.  The final proof is as follows: 
TAC_PROOF(([], ``! (l1:'a list) (l2:'a list).LENGTH (APP l1 l2) = LENGTH l1 + LENGTH l2``) ,
Induct_on `l1` THEN
 ASM_REWRITE_TAC[APP_def, LENGTH] THEN
 REWRITE_TAC[ADD_CLAUSES] THEN
 ASM_REWRITE_TAC[APP_def, LENGTH] THEN
 REWRITE_TAC[ADD_CLAUSES])

Comment: Excellent! If you shorten the proof a bit (hint: try [`REPEAT`](http://hol.sourceforge.net/kananaskis-8-helpdocs/help/Docfiles/HTML/Tactical.REPEAT.html)), I'll update the answer if you like.